# Unable to display the last Windows update patch applied using (New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate)

Tags: powershell

I'm unable to view the last installed KB patch into the **LastInstalledUpdates** column.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Get-ADComputer -Filter { operatingSystem -like '*Server*' } -Properties Name |
Where-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object {
    $ComputerName = $_
    Write-Host "Processing $($ComputerName) ..."
    $(
        Try {
            Invoke-Command -Cred $creds -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
                (New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results | Select-Object -Property `
                @{n = 'LastSearchDate'; e = { $_.LastSearchSuccessDate } },
                @{n = 'LastInstallDate'; e = { $_.LastInstallationSuccessDate } },
                @{n = 'LastBootTime'; e = { [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime) } },
                @{n = 'LastInstalledUpdates'; e = { $_ } }
            }
        }
        Catch {
            $_
        }
    ) | Select-Object -Property `
            @{n = 'Computer'; e = { $ComputerName } },
            LastSearchDate,
            LastInstallDate,
            LastBootTime,
            @{n = 'Error'; e = { $_.Exception.Message } },
            LastInstalledUpdates
} | Out-GridView
```

The column **LastInstalledUpdates** value is showing as: System.__ComObject
instead of the KBxxxx number.

Comment: That may mean that there are multiple values associated with `LastInstalledUpdates`

Comment: So how to display the last KB update number applied?

Comment: Specify the value you want.specifically

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. Thanks, Neko :-)